# How can I extrude without deformations?

Tags: modeling, extrude

I am modelling a wagon wheel. When I extruded, the tips got narrow. I wanted avoid this and kept it straight and thick.

Is there a way to keep them straight? Look at the picture. BTW, I wanted to fix this with Blender only, without any paid addon.

[image]

Comment: The missing spoke won't fit evenly in the remaining gap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A Cylinder for Each Spoke

Rather than extruding the spokes out of the rim, I would make a cylinder for each spoke.

You can do this manually by creating the first spoke then duplicate it and rotate each duplicate around the hub of the wheel. Or if you use Geometry Nodes you can set the number of spokes dynamically.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Search for **Extrude Faces Along Normals**

[image]

[image]